# Plugin problem. Question is not appearing.

Tags: plugins

I have installed a plugin [DW Q & A](http://www.designwall.com/guide/dw-question-answer-plugin/) and I have posted some questions on it too. But when I click on the questions it is not available. why?

The questions on the page: [image]

after clicking on a question 
[image]

**What is need to set up to view the questions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From plugin's page FAQ:

> If your updating makes your site inaccessible and your posts, questions return a 404 Error page, don’t panic, all your posts are still there and safe. What you need to do is fix the permalink settings of the DW Question & Answer plugin.

Make sure you are following instructions from "Permalink Settings".